# Unable to write the current timestamp to a file using BufferedWriter and FileWriter

Tags: java, file, file-io, filewriter, bufferedwriter

Here is my code :

```
 try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename))) {
            bufferedWriter.write(getCurrentTimeStamp()); //it is fetching current timestamp
            LOGGER.info("Current TS{}", getCurrentTimeStamp());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occcurred while writing to file ", e);

        }
```

I am not getting any errors.
My console prints -- Current TS:2020-10-20 10:58:23

But I am not able to see any changes in my file

I need to write to this file deleting the previous entry present.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what behaviour you are observing (compiler errors? runtime errors? No errors but the result isn't what you wanted?); you've merely stated what behaviour you wanted.

Comment: Pleas add an error description to your question: What isn't working as you expect? Does the code compile or do you get a compile error? Does the code run but throw an Exception or does it just not produce the output/result you expect?

Comment: sorry for less details, I have updated my question @rzwitserloot OH GOD SPIDERS

Comment: Is the problem: "The timestamp is appearing in the file, but at the end of it, I wanted it to overwrite it", or is the problem: "The file hasn't changed at all. Even the last modified time property of the file itself has not changed"?

Comment: As I mentioned,  I am not seeing any changes in my file, it is having the same thing I added while creating it